# Why `var one: AnyObject = [AnyObject]()` is valid?

Tags: swift, anyobject

I'm struggling to understand why an instance of `AnyObject` is equal to an array of `Anyobject`, i.e. Why this statement `var one: AnyObject = [AnyObject]()` is valid?

Comment: It is not uncommon that arrays are also objects (or can be bridged to objects). In Java, you can do `Object one = new Object[3];` as well.

Comment: For what it's worth, all you have to do to make this stop working is remove `import Foundation` from the top of your file.  A true Swift array is not an `AnyObject`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping out! love SO community so much lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this code

```
var one: AnyObject = [AnyObject]()
```

You are NOT comparing 2 values.

You are just assigning an array of `[AnyObject]` to a variable of type `AnyObject`.

Since the Swift array is bridged to `NSArray` (which is an object) then the compiler if ok with this code.

### Similar examples

In the code below we declare a variable of type AnyObject and we put an int into it. Since Int si bridged to NSNumber (which is an object) again it compiler perfectly fine

```
var one: AnyObject = 1
```

More examples

```
var word: AnyObject = "hello"
var condition: AnyObject = true
```

### Blocking the bridge to NSArray

If you remove the `import Foundation` line from Playground then the bridge to `NSArray` is interrupted.

Now the swift Array which is a struct is no longer considered a valid `AnyObject` (structs are not Objects) and you get a compile error.

[image]

Comment: sorry, I guess what i'm trying to ask is why is it legal to assign an array of AnyObject to an instance of AnyObject?

Comment: Because of automatic bridging to NSArray.

Comment: @TonyStark: When you declare a variable like this `var one: AnyObject` you can put into it any thingconform to the `AnyObject` protocol. Since the Swift array is bridged to `NSArray` which conforms to `AnyObject` then the code is valid.

Comment: @appzYourLife that make sense. Thank you so much for helping out! this has puzzled me for awhile now :)